# Facebook Login doesn't work anymore on update release of my existing app! What am I missing?

Tags: android, facebook-login

I've sent an update to my app on Play Store and now Facebook Login doesn't work anymore. I'm getting

`com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException: The supplied auth credential is malformed or has expired.`

error on my wife's phone. I've double-checked the KeyHash and SHA-1 Keys both for debug and release. All are correct! **What am I missing?** Is there anything to do before or after the release of an update? I've only added a nativeaddtemplate module from GITHUB. Is there something to do with it? I didn't change any code in the Login Activity. So I am not posting any code here.

I've tried almost anything! It happened before but that time I've added the KeyHash and the issue resolved but this time... I am kind of new so I need your help :)

Thank you very much in advance!

NOTE: I've checked almost every single question asked and answers for them on the web. They are not solving my issue. So believe me it is not a duplicated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Issue resolved. It was the location restriction that I have applied before accidentally.